# Does the Windows Phone Emulator in the Mango SDK run in VM

Tags: windows-phone-7

I know that this is strictly seen not a programming question but since it only concerns developers I'll ask it here.

Does the Emulator in the Mango SDK finally support running inside a VM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it does not. The Windows Phone Emulator requires a DirectX 10 or above capable graphics card with a WDDM 1.1 driver, which (AFAIK) is not emulated in any virtual machine environment.

Comment: I don't think it's a WDDM 1.1 driver, though.